# Thoughts on GoGrid vs EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, saas, gogrid

I am currently hosting my SaaS application at GoGrid (Microsoft stack).  Here's what I have:

- Database Server - physical box, 12 GB RAM, 2 X Quad Core CPU (2.13 GHz Xeon E5506)
- 2 Web / App servers - cloud servers, 2 GB RAM, 2 VCPUs
- 300 GB monthly bandwidth

I am paying around $900 / month for this.  My web / app servers are busting at the seams and need to be upgraded to 4 GB of RAM.  I also need a firewall, and GoGrid just added this service for an additional $200.  After the upgrade, I will be paying around $1,400.

I started looking at Amazon EC2, specifically this config:

- Database server - "High Memory Double Extra Large Instance" - 34 GB RAM, 13 EC2 compute units
- 2 Web / App servers - "Large Instance" - 7.5 GB RAM, 4 EC2 compute units

If I go with 1 year reserved instances, my upfront cost would be $4,500 and my monthly would be $700.  This comes to $1,075 / month when amortized.  Amazon also includes a firewall for free.

Here are my questions:

1. Do any of you have experience running a database (especially SQL Server) on an EC2 instance?  How did it perform compared to a dedicated machine?  One of my major concerns is with disk I/O.
2. Amazon's description of a compute unit is fairly vague.  Any ideas on how the CPU performance on the database servers would compare?

I am hoping that the Amazon solution will provide significantly better performance than my current or even improved GoGrid setup.  Having a virtual database server would also be nice in terms of availability.  Right now I would be in serious trouble if I had any hardware issues.

Thanks for any insight...

Answer (score 2):

I've used Amazon for SQL Server hosting and it is great.  We did not move from a dedicated machine to EC2 so I can't offer a comparison there but we have never had performance issues operating a relatively high volume - couple of hundred thousand transactions a day.

You can use an attached EBS volume for your data files to improve IO performance. My company used GoGrid before I arrived and had some bad experiences.  I can't speak to how they perform today.  All I can say is we are very happy with Amazon performance and reliability.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Do you know what type of instance you are running?

Comment: we run a m1.large for SQL Server, they have ami's with SQL pre-installed which is convenient.